# UIScrollView in a TabBar controlled navigation - IPhone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarControlled view navigation and i want to display a UIScrollView in one of the Tabs, but whenever i click on this tab the error-code:

```
...this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key...
```

appears.

My code:
Code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface BillViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
 IBOutlet UIScrollView *olta;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *olta;

@end
```

My code has a IBOutlet UIScrollView and it is connected to the IB.
My class also implements the desired protocol and the delegate is connected to the BillViewController-class.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your Interface Builder file. There is probably an outlet connected that doesn't exist anymore.

EDIT: Btw. you only have to add the IBOutlet macro once...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the Problem

The UIViewController set in the IB was wrong. It was set to a standard ViewController and not the my specific class with the appropiate protocol and the UIScrollView Outlet.

But thanks anyway ;)